# Inequalities with quadratics

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $$\frac{12}{x^2 + 2x} < \frac{3}{x^2 + 4x + 4}$$

I am confused. Can someone help me?
Update :
you can see my work in the comments. i figured out the answer but the answers other people gave was wrong. this might be useful to everyone

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you share what you've tried and what you're having trouble with? For example: Did you try factoring the denominator on either side?

Comment: @T.Bongers i did and i simplyfied it to (3(3x+8))/(x(x+2)^2) < 0

Comment: You should add that to the question, then. What are you having trouble with now? Notice that solving that inequality is the same as solving the inequality $(3x + 8) / x < 0$.

Comment: @T.Bongers how is it the same?

Comment: Thing about the sign of $(x + 2)^2$ (and take a little bit of care for when $x = -2$).

Comment: @T.Bongers ok how do i solve this

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to solve $(3x + 8) / x < 0$?

Comment: multiply by x to both sides and get 3x+8<0. then 3x<-8. then x<-8/3. is this the answer?

Comment: Not quite, since multiplying by $x$ can change the direction of the inequality.

Comment: @T.Bongers x>-8/3 ? is the the answer? thx

Comment: @T.Bongers thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

Begin with the inequality

$$\frac{12}{x^2+2x}<\frac{3}{x^2+4x+4}$$

Keep in mind that with an inequality, when multiplying or dividing by a negative number on both sides, the inequality reverses.  Here, we note that $x^2+4x+4=(x+2)^2\ge 0$.  Also, we have $x^2+2x=x(x+2)<0$ when $-2<x<0$ and $x(x+2)>0$ elsewhere.  Therefore, we have two cases.

---

**Case 1:**  $x>0$

Here, after multiplying both sides of the original inequality by $\frac13x(x+2)^2>0$, we find

$$4(x+2)<x\implies x<-\frac83$$

Therefore, there is no solution for $x>0$.

---

---

**Case 2:**  $x<0$, $x\ne -2$

Here, after multiplying both sides of the original inequality by $\frac13x(x+2)^2<0$, we find

$$4(x+2)>x\implies x>-\frac83$$

Therefore there is a solution for $-\frac83 <x<0$, $x \ne -2$.

---

We can combine the results from the cases and write

$$\frac{12}{x^2+2x}<\frac{3}{x^2+4x+4}$$

for $-\frac83< x<0$, $x\ne -2$.

Comment: how would i write it as a inequalaty?

Comment: @dan Dan, it seems that you are asking for help finding those values of $x$ for which the inequality is valid.  Is that correct?  - Mark

Comment: yes that is correct the question is solve the rational inequalaties

Comment: Dan, great!  Then, my answer provides the solution and a methodology showing how one can arrive at the solution.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark

Answer (score 1):

Write it as
$\frac{12}{x^2 + 2x} - \frac{3}{x^2 + 4x + 4}
< 0
$
or
$\frac{3 (3 x+8)}{x (x+2)^2}
< 0
$.

For this to be true,
we must have
$\frac{3 x+8}{x}
< 0
$.

You can work this out.

Comment: is it no solutions?

Comment: @dan There are solutions when $-\frac83 <x<0$.

Comment: But not *everywhere* $-\frac83 <x<0$

Comment: @DJohnM what do u mean "but now everywhere"

Comment: $x=-2$ in the original inequality will result in division by zero

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$\dfrac{1}{x+2}\cdot \left(\dfrac{12}{x}-\dfrac{3}{x+2}\right) < 0$